# Graphics around page number

Tags: lyx, koma-script, page-numbering

I have a book in my possession with page numbers that have graphics surrounding them. I was wondering if there were any way of accomplishing something like this in LaTeX. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image: Example of page number with graphics surrounding it]

My document uses the KOMA-script book class.

Thank you ahead of time for any help you can provide.

---

**UPDATE**: Using the recommendations by Salim Bou in their answer, this is the specific command that I used to get the effect desired:

```
\renewcommand{\pagemark}{{\color{gray}\vrule width0.1mm  height1.5ex depth2.5ex \ 
{\color{black}\arabic{page}}\color{gray}\ \vrule  width0.1mm height4ex depth0ex }}
```

It yields this result:

[image: Preview of result of command shown above]

*Note: The slight difference between the two lines may be a result of the .pdf viewer I'm using as it's variable from page to page.*

Comment: Renew the `pagemark` macro to use rules. You can use `raisebox` to vertically shift the rules. The height of the footer will change, leading to different output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a solution which  modify  `\pagemark` command and use `\vrule` to draw   rules beside page number, you can modify thickness of rule by adding `width<dim>` to  `vrule`  like this:

```
\vrule width1.5pt height1.5ex depth2.5ex
```

To change color of rules

```
{\color{your_color}\vrule width1.5pt height1.5ex depth2.5ex}
```

In this case you need to add `xcolor` package

---

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\pagemark}{{\color{gray}\vrule width1pt  height1.5ex depth2.5ex \ 
{\color{black}\arabic{page}}\ \vrule  width1pt height4ex depth0ex }}
\begin{document}

\lipsum 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked very well when I tried it, thank you. -- Though I will have to change the margins to compensate for the space that the lines took up vertically. The only question I have is this: is it possible to change the color of the lines? In my example picture and in the book I have, they're a lighter gray, so they don't draw so much attention.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: The width setting does not change the color, though. Is there a way to change the color, or is there only an option for changing the width? Thank you for the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`fancyhdr`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) along with [`TikZ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf). In the header, put

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr,tikz}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhead[RO,LE]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=20pt]
  \draw (0,0)--(0,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \thepage\ 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0)--(0,1);
  \end{tikzpicture}}
```

I do get a warning that the use of `fancyhdr` with `KOMA-Script` is not recommended, but the document does compile. Maybe `KOMA-Script` already has a way to play around with headers, in which case maybe it's possible to add the `TikZ` code there. Also, I used Texmaker instead of LyX (I don't have much experience with it), but hopefully it works with LyX as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Janis, but I'm wary of using something that results in a warning. I will keep those `fancyhdr` and `TikZ` in mind in the future, though -- as they may have other abilities that the other solution does not.